# How to display and count the result of filtering?

Tags: php, filtering

I have code like this :-

```
 <?php
    $string="cari naskah dengan edisi tahun 2017";
    $stopwords = array("dan", "dengan");
        foreach ($stopwords as &$word) {
        $word = '/\b' . preg_quote($word, '/') . '\b/';
        }
    $filter=preg_replace($stopwords,'', $string);
    echo $filter;
    $word = explode(" ",$filter);
        $jumlah = count($word);
        echo "<table border='1'>";
        echo "<tr><th>Kata</th></tr>";
        for ($i=0; $i <$jumlah; $i++)
        {
            echo "<tr><td>";
            echo "word $i = $word[$i]";
            echo "</td></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        echo "<b>Number of words : " .$jumlah. "</b><br>";
        echo "<br />";
    ?>
```

Output : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUMWL.png)

But, My expected output :

```
cari naskah edisi tahun 2017
Kata
word 0 = cari
word 1 = naskah
word 2 = edisi
word 3 = tahun
word 4 = 2017
Number of words : 5
```

How the solution of this problem? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple use `!in_array()` function

```
<?php
    $string="cari naskah dengan edisi tahun 2017";
    $stopwords = array("dan", "dengan");

        $word = explode(" ",$string);
        $jumlah = count($word);
        echo "<table border='1'>";
        echo "<tr><th>Kata</th></tr>";
        $i=0;
        foreach($word as $key=>$row)
        {  
            if(!in_array($row,$stopwords)){
            //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   

                echo "<tr><td>";
                echo "word $i = $word[$i]";
                echo "</td></tr>";

                $i++;
            }


        }
        echo "</table>";
        echo "<b>Number of words : " .$i. "</b><br>";
        echo "<br />";
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string="cari naskah dengan edisi tahun 2017";
    $stopwords = array("dan", "dengan");
        $jumlah_count = 0;
        $jumlah = count(explode(' ',$string));
        echo "<table border='1'>";
        echo "<tr><th>Kata</th></tr>";
        for ($i=0; $i <$jumlah; $i++)
        {

           if(!in_array($word[$i],$stopwords)){      
            echo "<tr><td>";
            echo "word $jumlah_count = $word[$i]";
            echo "</td></tr>";
              $jumlah_count++;                            
           }
        }
        echo "</table>";
        echo "<b>Number of words : " .$jumlah_count. "</b><br>";
        echo "<br />";
```